# File input/output and reading in a line

Tags: c++

So basically what my code wants me to do is read in from a file a line

> Movie name    MPAA Rating         Rating 1  Rating 2  Rating 3  Rating 4  Rating 5

I have this line of code that does that

```
file1 >> movieName >> mpaa >> rating1 >> rating2 >> rating3 >> rating4 >> rating5;
```

Example input(from first line in file):

> Frozen    PG13   1 2 3 4 5

That works perfectly.

But if I were to put in something like:

> Peter Pan    PG    1 2 3 4 5

I would get an error because it would try to put Pan in for mpaa and rating 1 would be PG and so on.
How do I get that code to recognize the space?

Comment: With a lot of suffering. You would be better off using commas or tabs to separate your values.

Comment: How would I do it with tabs?

Comment: Another alternative might be to grab the whole line, tokenize it, and then work backward and the name would be whatever is left over.  Of course, if more than one field can have spaces you're stuck with the delimiter approach which is generally the best option anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your separator to something else like commas, and try the following:

```
getline(file1, moveName, ',');
getline(file1, mpaa, ',');
// etc
```

If you need to read line by line and make sure each line is correct, you might want to first read the line with `getline(file1, line)`, and then use the string to initialize an `istringstream` to extract the comma separated values from.

Comment: Don't think I'm allowed to use commands, just tabs.
Would

    getline(file1, movieName, "\t", mpaa, "\t", "rating1");

Work?

Comment: @KevinD. Sure but `getline` only reads one value at a time, so `getline(file1, moveName, '\t')` etc. (you must specify a single `char`, e.g. `'\t'` not a string `"\t"`).

Comment: getline doesn't work with ints. Any suggestions? I feel like converting string to int would be a lot of work.

Comment: `std::stol` if your implementation supports it. You can also just use `getline` for `string`s and `operator>>` for `int`s, making sure to skip the comma after you have read an `int`.